Sql if one row has a value then don't display rest
I have customers that have more than one contract or none.  I only want to show customers that have either no contract or contracts that are not active (A) but also have a balance.  My current query selects these but I want to exclude the customer completely if they have even just one active contract.
SELECT T0.balance, *
FROM cust t0
left outer join Contracts t1 on t1.U_Code = t0.Code
Where (t1.U_Status != 'A'  or t1.U_Status is NULL) and t0.balance != 0 and CardType = 'c'
order by t0.balance

Sample Data



Cust
Balance
U_Status




A1
1
A


A2
2
A


A2
2
C


A3
1
C



Results Desired (since A2 has an active we don't care):



Cust
Balance
U_Status




A3
1
C




Really appreciate the edit, was struggling here

You can use a conditional windowed function to look across a whole set of data.
SELECT
  cu.balance, t1.*
FROM cust cu
left outer join (
    select *,
      count(case when co.U_Status = 'A' then 1 end) over (partition by co.U_Code) as count
    from Contracts co
) co on co.U_Code = t0.Code and
Where (co.count = 1 or co.count is null)
  and cu.balance != 0
  and cu.CardType = 'c'
order by
  cu.balance

If you didn't need the columns from Contracts then you could just flip it round into a NOT EXISTS
SELECT
  cu.*
FROM cust cu
where not exists (select 1
    from Contracts co
    where co.U_Code = cu.Code
      and co.U_Status = 'A'
  )
  and cu.balance != 0
  and cu.CardType = 'c'
order by
  cu.balance


I ended up not getting this notification and fixed this myself for:
SELECT T0.balance, * 
FROM cust t0  
left outer join Contracts t1 
    on t1.U_Code = t0.Code
Where (
    t1.U_Status != 'A'  
    or t1.U_Status is NULL
)
and t0.balance != 0 
and CardType = 'c' 
and t0.code not in (
    select U_code 
    from Contracts 
    where U_Status IN ('a') 
    group by U_code
)
order by t0.balance

